# Fortify Test Error: never uses the initial value it assigns to the variable

Tags: java, error-handling, fortify

I get this following error: The method getCDsByToken() in CDsImplTl.java never uses the initial value it assigns to the variable paymentCDApp on line 141

and this here is my code:

```
public GetCDsByTokenResponse getCDsByToken(String token) throws Exception {
        apiKey.setKey();
        IfPaymentCDApp paymentCDApp = new IfPaymentCDApp();

        try {
            String customerId = getCustomerIdByCDId(token);
            RetrieveCDCommand retrieveCDCommand = getRetrieveCDCommand(customerId, token);
            CD cD = null;
            cD = retrieveCDCommand.execute();
            paymentCDApp = AppUtils.mapStripeCDToExtCD(cD);
        }
```

I don't understand the error message so far, what do I have to look up? I mean everything is used what is not correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IfPaymentCDApp paymentCDApp = new IfPaymentCDApp();
```

In the above code, you are assigning `paymentCDApp` with an object. But, later in the try block, you are assigning the same variable another value;

```
paymentCDApp = AppUtils.mapStripeCDToExtCD(cD);
```

The value you assigned before (given by `IfPaymentCDApp paymentCDApp = new IfPaymentCDApp();`) is never used between that line and the line which contains `paymentCDApp = AppUtils.mapStripeCDToExtCD(cD);`. That's why you are getting such an error.

You can initialize the variable to `null` at the beginning which is a much better practice.

```
apiKey.setStripeApiKey();
IfPaymentCDApp paymentCDApp = null;

try {
    String customerId = getCustomerIdByCDId(token);
    RetrieveCDCommand retrieveCDCommand = getRetrieveCDCommand(customerId, token);
    CD cD = null;
    cD = retrieveCDCommand.execute();
    paymentCDApp = AppUtils.mapStripeCDToExtCD(cD);
}
```

You may need to do a null check after the try block in order to determine whether the correct value was assigned. I cannot give any suggestion since you haven't put the code after the try block. However, initializing the variable to null will solve your problem.

Comment: if I implement that your way Eclipse wants me to add a @SuppressWarnings(null), I have to go that way ? or is there a way I could implement your way without SurpressWarnings

Comment: That is why I said that you need a null check. `if(paymentCDApp!=null)` to make sure your things went well. One more thing, are you sure `The method getCDsByToken() in CDsImplTl.java never uses the initial value it assigns to the variable paymentCDApp on line 141` is an error? Or is it just another warning?

Comment: I am doing that stuff in fortify and it is marked as and issue, but also marked with low priority so I don't know if I have to solve that or leave it that way

Comment: It should be just a warning. Try to compile your original code and it will not given any error.

Comment: can I solve that warning by just initializing with `IfPaymentCDApp paymentCDApp; `  ?

Comment: No. You need to initialize it to `null` or new object as in your code. Both will give its own warnings. Just ignore them if you are sure about your logic